# CASE statement returning the same value regardless of input

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a case statement where it returns **2** regardless of the value from **v_trcdate**. The **v_trcdate** is supposed to be from a table value. Then, I've tried manually inputting the value and still the same result.

```
Declare v_trcdate DATE := '10-JAN-23';


  (CASE WHEN v_accesstype = 'Y' THEN 
     (CASE WHEN TRUNC(sysdate)  < v_trcdate  THEN 1 WHEN TRUNC(sysdate) > v_trcdate THEN 2 END)
        ELSE 3 END) AS PRICE
```

Comment: What is your session's `nls_date_format`?  What happens if you use an actual date literal `v_trcdate date := date '2023-01-10'`?

Comment: The `nls_date_format` is `DD-MON-RR` @JustinCave

Comment: I've tried the date literal, it looks like it worked. I still need to do some more test to confirm it.

Comment: That makes me believe that your `nls_date_format` is not what you think it is.  If, for example, it was set to `DD-MON-YYYY`, then the string "01-JAN-23" would be interpreted as the year 0023 (1999 years ago) not 2023.

Comment: Are you sure that is your *session* NLS setting, not just the database default? The behaviour suggests your session has DD-MON-YYYY (or less likely, YY-MON-DD). [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ffc18c4f6ba8b372fa1f12b22653464) - what do you see if you add debugs to your version? You shouldn't rely on implicit conversion anyway - use a proper date literal, or an explicit `to_date()` with the correct format mask for your string.

Comment: Always use the `'yyyy-MM-dd'` date format for date literals!

Comment: That might be the case @JustinCave

Comment: I used the query SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS for the nls_date_format  @AlexPoole

Comment: well, you are declaring the variable v_trcdate to be a DATE, but then you are assigning it a string value, thus forcing an implicit use of to_date to convert that string to a DATE.  And that implied use of to_date will rely on the session setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  That, in itself, is a formula for failure.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the value to a date literal?  `to_char(v_trcdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` works when displaying the value, but doesn't work when used to compare with **SYSDATE**